# Excel VBA Dynamic Ranges/Index selections

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to create a talent calculator for myself, and the entire first sheet calls to a Data sheet that does all the background work.  On the excel sheet itself, everything calls to INDEX(TableName,Row,Column) because it's much easy to keep track of and I find I often have to move data around while working on it so handling Names is easier than handling cell references.

However, I also use VBA on this sheet, and I'm rather new to it.  Instead of, for example, using Range("C1"), if C1 was part of table TableOne, would there be a way to reference it like in the Excel formulas such as INDEX(TableOne,1)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Range, you can simply use `Worksheets(...).Cells(row, column)`, or if TableOne is a named Range, then `Range("TableOne").Cells(row, column)`.
I'm not all sure if that's all you need...

Comment: I'm aware of the Cells() though that still means that I'd have to use an exact reference.  I will try Range("Table") and see if that works.

I need something that works like the INDEX() function in Excel.